# Get the div by the data-checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the div when it presents the value of "no" in the data-checked.

how can I do this in JavaScript?

```
<div class="checkbox quote-form-element" data-checked="yes" data-name="Política de Privacidade">
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you read the documentation for jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an Attribute Selector(docs: [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Attribute_Selectors)):

```
$('div[data-checked="no"]')
```

Or:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-checked="no"]') // get just one element
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-checked="no"]') // get a collection of elements
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdg4ms9/).

Comment: I think they would need `querySelectorAll` as a drop in replacement for `$('div[data-checked="no"]')`, otherwise they are going to get one element, not a collection

Comment: @RobM. you're right, but it seems op is dealing with just one element, but anyway, its a good idea.

Comment: the first way is identifying the value of "yes" and "no" to occur as "no".

Comment: @PedroHenriqueKuzminskas your html snnipet constains a div with `data-checked="yes"`, but your questions asks for a selector to get the `no` value, so I used it. hahaha

Comment: in six minutes i'll click to accept your answer, you helped me a lot in this

Comment: @MaxZoom you can be right on this, but is ok to suggest OP to use a filter loop when he probably doesn't needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery selector for `div` with a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) as below

```
$('div').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).data("checked") == "no"; 
  })
)
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdg4ms9/2/)

Comment: Is this not less efficient?

Comment: It's not. Such selectors are handled by the CSS engine. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: This is just an example. For better performance use more specific selector i.e `$('div.checkbox')`